# Add glassfish 2.x server to a netbeans ide

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

I'm trying to add a glassfish v2.1.1 server to my netbeans servers, and after install the glassfish 2.x plugin, selecting my glassfish 2.1 location, shows the next error:

```
Run setup.xml or setup-cluster.xml before attempting to register
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must follow the steps described here: http://glassfish.java.net/downloads/v2ur2-b04.html. Speccially this step: 
`% lib\ant\bin\ant -f setup.xml`

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I had already done it, but still that was the answer.